# Finding a 94% Confidence Interval for μ1 - μ2

Tags: statistics

Question :

> A random sample of size n1 = 25, taken from a normal population with a
>   standard deviation σ1 = 5, has a mean1 = 80.
>
> A second random sample of size n2 = 36, taken from a different normal
>   population with a standard deviation σ2 = 3, has a mean2 = 75.
>
> Find a 94% confidence interval for μ1 - μ2.

```
Ans : 2.9 < μ1 - μ2 < 7.1
```

---

I tried this :
[image]

Where does the wrong come?

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: I will answer you tomorrow morning - bed time.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let random variables $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ be sample means from random samples drawn from our two distributions. Let $W=\bar{X}-\bar{Y}$.  Then $W$ has mean $\mu_1-\mu_2$. So it is an unbiased estimator of $\mu_1-\mu_2$.

The random variable $W$ has **normal** distribution. The **variance** of $W$ is $\frac{25}{25}+\frac{9}{36}$.